# New controller in ASP.NET Core 5 MVC

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, .net-5

I have an existing ASP.NET Core 5 MVC application.

I added a new controller and the application crashes on the line

```
endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
            name: "default",
            pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```

with the following error:

> System.TypeLoadException: 'Could not load type 'System.Web.HttpContextBase' from assembly 'System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'

Here is what I have in my `startup.cs`:

```
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseWebOptimizer();
    app.UseStaticFiles();

    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseMvc();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
            name: "default",
            pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    });
```

And this is my new controller:

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using Solobal.Accounts.Api.Configuration;

namespace Solobal.Accounts.Api.Controllers
{
    public class ExternalUrlController : Controller
    {
        private readonly AppSettings appSettingsConfig;

        public ExternalUrlController(IOptions<AppSettings> options)
        {
            this.appSettingsConfig = options.Value;
        }

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return this.Redirect(this.appSettingsConfig.ExternalUrl);
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: It seems you've mixed up .NET Framework 4 assemblies with .NET *Core* 5. BTW .NET (Core) 5 is already out of support. It was only a single-year "current" version. The long-term versions are .NET Core 3.1 (reaching End Of Life in December 2022) and .NET 6, supported until November 2024

Comment: Your new controller is directly referencing .NET Framework 4 namespaces `using System.Web.Mvc;`. Why? You can't use anything from that namespace in .NET Core

Comment: You are right. I've resolved the issue by replacing using System.Web.Mvc; with using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;